# Twitter + spring social , Authentication Eror

Tags: twitter

I tried to build an application to connect to Twitter and post tweets. I created twitter template using spring social.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

twitter template

```
return new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken,
                accessTokenSecret);
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
```

I added Read and Write permissions under app settings in the developer portal as well.

logs, of HTTPS calls, made to Twitter

```
    12:19:49.750 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /1.1/statuses/update.json HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.751 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.751 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.751 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="2562115169", oauth_token="my_token", oauth_consumer_key="my_key", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1632466188", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="iwmB09dBm2R7SJ07w8CAlN4EiT8%3D"[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 27[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: api.twitter.com[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_231)[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.752 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
12:19:49.753 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "status=Test+eng+model+tweet"
12:19:50.257 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
```

What am I missing, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance